# FormData in Jquery is empty and nothing is working

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

I have gone through every link to similar questions and none of the solutions helped.
My console.log(formData) is always empty! And the ajax posts null for POST and FILES var dump in the PHP file.

My HTML is this

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='updmenform'>
<div><label>Item</label><input type="text" name="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName" required></div>
<div><label>Category</label>
<select name='CategoryCode' required>
    <option value='Food' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Food"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Food</option>
    <option value='Desserts' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Desserts"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Desserts</option>
    <option value='Beverages' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Beverages"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Beverages</option>
            <option value='Miscellaneous' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Miscellaneous"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Miscellaneous</option>
</select></div>
<div><label>Unit</label><input type="text" name="Unit" placeholder="Unit" required></div>
<div><label>Description</label><input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description" required></div>
<div><label>Rate</label><input type="text" name="Rate" placeholder="Rate"></div>
<div><label>Image</label><input type="file" name="pimage" id='pimage' required></div>

<div><label></label><input type="submit" name="menusub" value="Submit" id='menusub'></div>
</form>
```

And the JQuery

```
$("form#updmenform").submit(function(){
 event.preventDefault();
if( window.FormData !== undefined ) 
{
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(formData);
 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updmenu.php',  //Path to the server script that process the data
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
      //  xhr: function() {  },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
     });
}else {
        alert('FormData Undefined');
    }
});
```

The Console.log

> formData{}

Have been breaking my head from past three days. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the values is to use formData.entries.
You could convert it to an array like below:

```js
$("form#updmenform").submit(function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
      var form = document.querySelector('form');
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      const values = [...formData.entries()];
      console.log(values);
   } else {
      alert('FormData Undefined');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='updmenform'>
   <div><label>Item</label><input type="text" name="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName" required></div>
      <div>
      <label>Category</label>
      <select name='CategoryCode' required>
         <option value='Food' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Food"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Food</option>
         <option value='Desserts' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Desserts"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Desserts</option>
         <option value='Beverages' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Beverages"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Beverages</option>
         <option value='Miscellaneous' <?php if(isset($_POST['CategoryCode']) && $_POST['CategoryCode']=="Miscellaneous"){ echo "Selected =Selected";}?>>Miscellaneous</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div><label>Unit</label><input type="text" name="Unit" placeholder="Unit" required></div>
   <div><label></label><input type="submit" name="menusub" value="Submit" id='menusub'></div>
</form>
```

[Documentation](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-formdata/)

Comment: Thank you. This is still not posting anything to the php file....i am getting null for var dumps of $_POST and $_FILES in the ajax call back